# SearchController not showing searchbar when wrapped in another view

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following setup where the `Searchbar` in `SearchController` only gets visibility if directly added to the view ( not as a child of another view ). My setup,

```swift
    // The controller that initiates a search

    private lazy var searchResultViewController:
    ViewController = {
        let controller = SearchResultViewController.instantiate() // utility to instantiate from storyboard
        return controller
    }()
    
    private lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultViewController)
        controller.showsSearchResultsController = true
        controller.definesPresentationContext = false
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultViewController
        controller.searchBar.delegate = searchResultViewController
        controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        controller.searchBar.setValue("Cancel", forKey: "cancelButtonText")
        return controller
    }()
```

I am showing the `searchbar` in `tableView's` header.

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
          return UITableView.automaticDimension
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
          return .leastNonzeroMagnitude
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
          return searchController.searchBar 
          // If I pass it directly, the searchcontroller shows the searchbar
      }
```

Now, the problem is, I have a wrapper view around it like I want to have a filter button horizontally.

```swift
    private lazy var headerStackView: UIStackView = {
        let searchBarView = searchController.searchBar
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [searchBarView, pickerButton])
        stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.backgroundColor = .white
        stackView.spacing = 0
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        return stackView
    }()
```

Now if I pass this as header view,

```swift
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
          return headerStackView // It does not show when searchcontroller opens
      }
```

So, when `searchController` opens the `searchResultController` the `searchBar` only gets visibility if it doesn't get wrapped in another view.

Any insight?

Comment: Actually, I want that custom view only on the parent table view header, not on the searchcontroller's searchBar. When I tap on it, the searchcontroller that opens should only have the default searchbar view, nothing custom.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand the problem then.

Comment: What I don't get is if I provide `searchController.searchBar` in the table header it works perfectly, just wrapping it in a `UIStackVIew` doesn't work.